# Why the identity mapper can get out of memory?

Tags: java, hadoop, out-of-memory, amazon-emr

In an reduce-only Hadoop job input files are handled by the identity mapper and sent to the reducers without modification. In some job of mine I got very surprised to see the job failing in the map phase with "Out of memory error" and "GC overhead limit exceeded".

In my understanding, a memory leak on the identity mapper is out of the question.
What can be the cause of such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours of researching and trial and error I realized that the machines I provisioned for the TASK group were small instances with not much memory and, more interestingly, that the point in which I was running out of memory was during shuffling instead of mapping.

Comment: Can you let me know how you figured out this was happening during the shuffle phase? I'm hitting a similar issue with reducers.

Comment: I realized that looking deep at the OOM traces. The exceptions were raised in functions of Hadoop related with shuffling.

Comment: @sortega I'm getting the same error but on 4-node cluster each has 17GB memory on Elastic MapReduce cluster. Could you please explain your data (size, rows, columns, etc.)? Mine is about 223GB MongoDB dump file in bson format.